# Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7

net project in vs2010 i have a db and table inside the app_data folder, i have created a deployment package and have imported the package into an iis server that is installed on my local mechine.
now i get this error message while trying to preform an insertion.

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed

the connection string is:

> Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\survey.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

when running it inside VS2010 it`s working fine.

how can i solve this probelm ?

Comment: Are you running the app pool or web app under different credentials?

Comment: leppie , i am sorry but i dont know what you are talking about.

Comment: Can you show us your connection string ??

Comment: yes, i have added the connection string.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1086442/908336), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/281626/908336), and [there](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `User Instance=True`. You don't need [RANU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) instances. Next, make sure the SQL Server Express [service account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx) had the proper needed rights on your app_data:

```
cacls <path\app_data> /E /T /G SQLServerMSSQLUser$<ComputerName>$SQLEXPRESS:F
```

Comment: if i deploy my app on a remote server with sql server 2005 (not express) do i need to do the same ?

Comment: The `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|...` functionality is supported exclusively by Express. Non-express editions instance have to properly attach the database permanently and the database has to be located on the remote server.

Comment: i will ask this differently , do i need to define a db and table on the server where i want to upload my app , or its enough i did that in vs ?

Comment: The database deployment strategy will depend from case to case. The VS style deployment for ASP.Net via app_data contained .MDF files is usually only useful in demos or in hosted scenarios. Proper deployment on a real world non-hosted scenario implies  careful planing of the database location, deployment and upgrade scripts, and is never done by working on the database model from VS.

Comment: so i need to create the same db on the server and make a new connection string but i can keep my code ?

Answer (score 7):

This article helped solved this issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980

**Edit** From the MSDN article (in case the link disappears):

> **Resolution for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2**
>
> For all web applications running under IIS 7.5, regardless of their
>   project type, carry out the following steps:
>
> 1. Run the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager tool.  This tool can be accessed either from the Administrative start menu, or by
>      typing "inetmgr" in the Windows Start-->Search textbox and selecting
>      the inetmgr tool.
> 2. In the left-hand pane of the IIS Manager tool expand the machine node. Click on the "Application Pools" node so that the application
>      pools display in the main window of the management tool.
> 3. If you are troubleshooting an ASP.NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 application select the "DefaultAppPool" application pool.  For ASP.NET v4 select
>      the "ASP.NET v4.0" application pool.
> 4. Right-click on the selected application pool and choose "Advanced Settings"
> 5. In the "Advanced Settings" dialog box find the category called "Process Model".  The first row in the category will be the "Identity"
>      row.
> 6. Click on the "Identity" row and then click on the small button that shows on the right-hand side of the value cell.  The button
>      displays the text "…"
> 7. A dialog box called "Application Pool Identity" will popup.  Within that dialog box there are two radio buttons.  Make sure the
>      first radio button titled "Built-in Account" is selected.
> 8. In the dropdown box below the radio button choose "Network Service" for the identity.
> 9. Click "Ok" to close out the "Application Pool Identity" dialog box.
> 10. Click "Ok" to close out the "Advanced Settings" dialog box.
> 11. At this point the changes to the application pool identity will have been saved to IIS 7.5's configuration store.
>
> **Resolution for Web Application Projects and Websites**
>
> For web application projects (WAP) and websites located in a user's
>   Documents Folder hosted under any version of IIS running as NETWORK
>   SERVICE, carry out the following steps:
>
> 1. First confirm that IIS has been configured to run as NETWORK SERVICE.  This is the default on IIS6 and IIS7.  However if you are
>      running on Windows 7 or Window Server 2008 R2 you will first need to
>      follow the steps above in "Resolution for Windows 7 and Windows Server
>      2008 R2" to make IIS application pools run as NETWORK SERVICE.
> 2. From a command prompt, type net stop iisadmin /y .  This will cause any running ASP.NET WAP applications to shutdown.
> 3. Exit out of all running Visual Studio instances.
> 4. NETWORK SERVICE must be granted Read permission to the top-level Visual Studio folder located in your user's Documents folder.  The
>      Visual Studio folder will have different names depending on the
>      version:  "Visual Studio 2005", "Visual Studio 2008", or "Visual
>      Studio 2010".
> 5. NETWORK SERVICE must be granted both read and write permissions to your project's top-level project folder.  For example if your WAP
>      project is called "MyCustomWebProject", then the folder
>      "Documents\Visual Studio 20xx\Projects\MyCustomWebProject" needs to
>      have read and write access enabled for NETWORK SERVICE.  Or, if your
>      webiste project is called "MyCustomWebProject", then the folder
>      "Documents\Visual Studio 20xx\Websites\MyCustomWebProject" needs to
>      have read and write access enabled for NETWORK SERVICE.
> 6. NETWORK SERVICE must be granted both read and write permissions to the App_Data folder located within your web project's directory
>      structure.

Comment: In addition: 1)turn off your SQL Server 2) remove all files from SQLSERVER directory 3) Check that its service is run under NETWORK SERVICE account 4) turn on it again. 

Details are here: http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2011/01/20/sql-server-express-and-vs2010-web-application-mdf-file-errors.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The solution with me is

```
   - On IIS ->> Application pool
   - Select Default App Pool (it may be different of your website, please choose your pool)
   - Advanced setting
   - Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity
   - Load user profile: change to true Restart IIS
```

Answer (score 4):

SOLUTION FOR ENVIROMENT:

Win 7, IIS 7.0, Visual Studio 2010, Database.mdf File

Open the web config and check the conexion string:

Important, make sure the AttachDbFilename is NOT followed by C:\inetpub\<>\App_Data\

```
<add name="conexion" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;
    Integrated Security=True;
    User Instance=True" />
```

In IIS 7.0 Go to ApplicationPools, find the application pool created for the application.

- Click Advanced Settings
- Go to Identity and open it  Select Custom
- Account and set the PC or Server user admin account

Then go to the WebSite in IIS 7.0 and click it...

- Locate and double click the Authentication icon
- Click on Anonymous Authentication and select Edit, then Select Application Pool Identity

  Locate the ASP.NET Impersonation and edit, Select on Specify User and then enter the credentials.

Restart IIS:
cmd > iisreset/noforce
or click the reset image button

Answer (score 0):

RUN->INETMGR->
go to Sites select your Site
Then go to Right panel and look for "Basic Settings"
Then Click on "Connect as" Then Select "Specific User" Then Click "Set" 
Enter Local PC User Name And Password Then Click "OK"

Then Click on "Test Setting" if you see Both options are green then Ok. 
Problem Solved
Enjoy...