# Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the users local application data path

Tags: asp.net

Everything is working fine on my local computer but when i published the web site on internet i get the error "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed"

Comment: Please provide more information.  Useful information in this case would be: SQL Connection String (be sure to obscure or replace any user names or passwords for your safety), a description of your server environment (windows version, sql server version, is it a dedicated hosting solution, or a public cloud service?).  How did you deploy your web site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770596/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-due-to-failure-in-retrieving-th)