# "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375857/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-th)

i am using sql server 2005 full edition and here's my connection string :

```
 <add name="xx" connectionString="Data Source=xx\SQL2005;Initial Catalog=xx;Connect Timeout=180;uid=xx;pwd=xx;"/>
```

i am using attached db on Sql server not connectting to mdf file .
this issue is appeared after deploying and it works fine when running on VS

how can i solve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before:

[Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375857/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-th)

Perhaps there's something useful in there?