# Membership.GetUser() -> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

If i try to call `Membership.GetUser();`, I get this error: "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed."

Other than that, membership works, so I can create a new user and log in with it.

(At first, I kept getting the sql sever 2008 and 2008 r2 compatibility error, so I deleted 2008 and installed 2012. )

What should I do?

Comment: Is there a membership user logged on when you call that code?  What is in `HttpContext.Current.User.Name` when you make that call?

Comment: Check your connection string and should be opened ?

Comment: If push comes to shove.......you can (1) Create your own class which implements SqlMembershipProvider.....(2) change your config to use this Custom Membership Provider......(3) override the method that is causing you issues........ and see if you can figure out any extra stuff while in the debugger.  That's weird that one method fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried this solution once again: (I did it a few days ago, but I installed SQL Express 2012 since): [Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375857/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-th), and this time it worked!