# Simple Authentication Method causes error when login is incorrect

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a simple login function:

```
    private bool AdminIsValid(string username, string password)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        using (var db = new AdminEntities())
        {

            var admin = db.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.password.Trim() == password);

            if (admin != null)
            {
                if (admin.uname.Trim() == username)
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

That I use like this:

```
    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (AdminIsValid(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(LoginUser.UserName, false);
                Response.Redirect("../");
            }
            else
            {
               //"Log in data failed"
            }           
    }
```

It only works when the login is successful, when it fails I get this error:

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in
>   starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be
>   closed.
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Good afternoon, maybe this [post][1] can be of assistance.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375857/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-th

Comment: @mreyeros I seen this already, it didnt help thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by replacing all `ApplicationServices` connection strings with my own.

Then I ran the following command:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S DBServerName -U DBLogin -P DBPassword -A all -d DBName
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `User Instance=True` in your connection string, remove that. Also you should compare user name and password together, since multiple users can have a same password, you can modify your method like:

```
private bool AdminIsValid(string username, string password)
{
    using (var db = new AdminEntities())
    {
       return db.users.Any(u => u.password.Trim() == password &&
                                u.uname.Trim() == username);
    }
}
```

Comment: This make sense, I found that in `ApplicationServices` connection string which I don't use, when removing it I get error CANNOT CREATE DATBASE