# login failed for user 'domain\name'

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, aspnetdb

I have tried to setup and installed PHP and MySql in IIS because I want to try PHP web development, and after doing that, I have checked the websites I have created in Visual Studio to check if the websites I have created in ASP.net and MSSQL were affected. When I tried to run the asp.net websites I have created and tried to login to those websites I started to get the error:

`Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance"`

So what I did was, uninstall MySQL because I was afraid that it was the cause of my problem in MSSQL. After uninstalling, I started to get the error:

`login failed for user 'domain\name'`

whenever I try to login to my asp.net websites.

Please help me in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14154699/542398

Comment: I no longer get the error "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed" after deleting MySQL however I am still getting the error login failed for user 'domain\name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *try*:

Delete:

1. C:\Documents and Settings\\ASPNET\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data
2. C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS