# If add [user instances=true] to connection string, an exception is thrown

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, connection-string

Exception Details:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: can not open the logon request database  "RealtyDB" 
>   login failed. account 'FAFHN24BNK43\JKAD754' login failed.

My connection string looks like this:

```
add name = "ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;User Instance=True;Initial Catalog=RealtyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

if I removed the `[User Instance=True;]`, my application will be fine.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown ?

Comment: Are you using [User Instance] on purpose? Can you explain why you are using it? (In other words, my answer would be, "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." Doctor: "Don't do that.")

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just want to know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've only ever seen the user instance feature used in combination with `AttachDbFileName`. In other words, you can't connect to a database that is already attached to a running instance of SQL Server, and tell SQL Server to spin up a new instance for that database, since only one instance can "own" a database at a time. When you use `AttachDbFileName`, it tells SQL Server to make a *copy* of that MDF file for the use of the application.

So, unless this is the way you intend to use this feature, I'll suggest again that you just take the `User Instance = true` parameter out of your connection string.

(It may also be interesting to note that this questionably useful feature has been deprecated.)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Aaron Bertrand. The connection string should be like this,

connectionString= "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\appdb.mdf; User Instance=true"