# SQL Server 2014 Express : Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance

Tags: .net, windows-8.1, sql-server-2014-express

I have a .net wpf application running on Windows 8 & 8.1 making use of SQL Server 2014 Express.

The following error keeps coming back (usually after a restart):

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed. 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

I looked at the following similar posts:

[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-se)

[Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375857/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-th)

I have changed the user the services runs under to Local System.

I have written a scripts which stops the `SQLExpress2014` service deletes all files under the `C:\Documents and Settings\{YOUR_USERNAME}\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\{SQL_INSTANCE_NAME}` folder and then restarts the service.

Running the script fixes the issue temporarily but then it usually start occurring again after a restart requiring the script to be rerun.

The following is my application connection string:

```
metadata=res://*/Models.###.csdl|res://*/Models.###.ssdl|res://*/Models.###.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS2014;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\###.mdf;Database=###;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;User Instance=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;
```

Is there something else I have to do to prevent this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing and being unable to resolve the issue I decided to turn off "User Instance" and address the legacy reasons why it was on in the first place.

This is probably a good move anyway as the user instance feature has been deprecated in favour of LocalDB:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh510202.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx