# Why does this Visual Studio warning / problem occur?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I get this error whenever I want to access the database that I have created and it shows this message

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: how does the connection string look like

Comment: Try this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-se